# How can I pass an env name to Cypress tests to load a set of env variables?

Tags: cypress

How can I pass an env name to Cypress tests to load a set of env variables?  The Cypress page remains cryptic and does not answer this question:  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-2-cypress-env-json

Also, their example does it in a way that would force me to write shell scripts to handle switching variables: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/server-communication__env-variables .  There is no way hard-coding the env name is going to work for me: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/2e5fb3da420f544637ff77d81ff7261f5d2164e8/examples/server-communication__env-variables/cypress/integration/spec.js#L5

So, I created a file called `cypress.playground.json` but I don't know how to tell Cypress to load it up.

```
{
    "baseUrl": "https://my-url.hostname/ui/",
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000,
    "video" : true
}
```

And, when running from command line.  This is me "guessing" how to pass the env value:

```
✘-1 ~/Documents/GitHub/me [Branch-Name|✔] 
16:35 $ cypress run --headed --browser chrome --env playground
Cypress encountered an error while parsing the argument env

You passed: playground

The error was: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
✘-1 ~/Documents/GitHub/me [Branch-Name|✔] 
16:35 $ cypress run --headed --browser chrome --config playground
Cypress encountered an error while parsing the argument config

You passed: playground

The error was: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

My intention here is to override the default value of `baseUrl` before running my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the variant I came up with.

This difference is you can combine `cypress.json` with your specified file e.g `cypress.playground.json`

**/plugins/index.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (on, config) => {

  const configFile = `cypress.${config.env['env-file']}.json` // relative to project root
  const addConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configFile))
  const combinedConfig = { ...config, ...addConfig }  // overwrites keys like baseUrl

  return combinedConfig
}
```

**Command line**

```js
yarn cypress open --env env-file=playground
```

**cypress.playground.json**

```js
{
  "baseUrl": "http://example.com"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I found that answer at https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/configuration-api#Switch-between-multiple-configuration-files